# My Followers are not able to see any of my notifications on Twitter. What could be causing this?

Tags: twitter

My followers on Twitter have been unable to view my likes, retweets, and mentions for almost a week.

I have placed 2 tickets, and sent multiple messages to @support and have not received anything from any of them.

Is there any reason that this would be happening? Everything is showing up on the followers Time Lines, just not their notifications tab.

I have tried the app on an Android Phone, and tablet. Twitter in several Web Browsers, and TweetDeck on both Windows 10, and Ubuntu Linux.